# Getting JSON data using $http

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http, angular-http

I am trying to get the JSON data using the `$http` function; I am always getting error for this. Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="x in code">
     {{ x.code }}
   </li>
</ul>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get("data.json")
   .success(function (response) {$scope.code = response;})
   .error(function (response) {alert("Error")})
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my data.json file:

```
{
  "code":"#include <stdio.h>

          int main()
          {
             printf('Hello world');
             return 0;
          }"
}
```

Here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Q4dsCjHM3ykgp2SaHw35?p=preview

Comment: your data is not a proper json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do change your data to below.Basically it should be string, use `pre` tag for line break & then replace enter by `\n`

```
{
  "code": "#include <stdio.h>\n int main()\n printf('Hello world');\n return 0;\n}"
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in code">
    <pre>{{ x }}</pre>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/tIssCfuOAqPkIohHfL0t?p=preview)

Comment: How can I include line breaks can u help me

Comment: Where should I include the pre tag . Can i include in json file.

Comment: @RamanaUday it should be html check my html in answer, it should be inside `li` tag `<pre>{{ x }}</pre>`

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is poorly formatted. The `string` line of code should be on one line e.g.,

```
{
    "code": "#include <stdio.h> int main() ...."
}
```

You can always validate your JSON at [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com)

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not well formated.

**JSON**

```
{
  "code":"#include <stdio.h>int main(){printf('Hello world');return 0;}"
}
```

Then, you can access to the `code` field in your request :

**Controller**

```
$http.get("data.json")
  .success(function (response) {
    $scope.code = response.code;
})
.error(function (response) {
    alert("Error");
});
```

Comment: why you need `response.data`?

Comment: Why ? Yes no need of `response.data`, just saying `response.code` to retrieve the data of the field `code` into the JSON

Comment: because you already have data in your first option..if you used `.then` then only you will need to say `reponse.data`, though response.code is correct.I'm removing my downvote. Thanks :)